# XML to YAML convert

Tags: xml, symfony, yaml

How can I convert this into `yml`:

```
    <service id="fos_user.mailer.twig_swift" class="FOS\UserBundle\Mailer\TwigSwiftMailer" public="false">
        <argument type="service" id="mailer" />
        <argument type="service" id="router" />
        <argument type="service" id="twig" />
        <argument type="collection">
            <argument key="template" type="collection">
                <argument key="confirmation">%fos_user.registration.confirmation.template%</argument>
                <argument key="resetting">%fos_user.resetting.email.template%</argument>
            </argument>
            <argument key="from_email" type="collection">
                <argument key="confirmation">%fos_user.registration.confirmation.from_email%</argument>
                <argument key="resetting">%fos_user.resetting.email.from_email%</argument>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </service>
```

now I've got this far in converting:

```
fos_user.mailer.twig_swiftr:
    class: FOS\UserBundle\Mailer\TwigSwiftMailer
    arguments: ['@mailer', '@router', '@twig']
```

this  `<argument type = "collection">` is the line I am stucked with. Thanks.

Comment: You can convert this automatically now with the [Symfony2 Service Config Converter](http://converter.rosstuck.com/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
fos_user.mailer.twig_swiftr:
    class: FOS\UserBundle\Mailer\TwigSwiftMailer
    arguments:
        - @mailer
        - @router
        - @twig
        - { template: { confirmation: %fos_user.registration.confirmation.template%, resetting: %fos_user.resetting.email.template% }, from_email: { confirmation: %fos_user.registration.confirmation.from_email%, resetting: %fos_user.resetting.email.from_email% } }
```

Check this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html#collections

Comment: You've hit it! Thanks.. I am new to YAML, your answer give me hints for my future applications.. that help me a lot...

Answer (score 5):

There is a neat and simple online tool for converting Symfony *[XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)* config to *[YAML](http://yaml.org/)*.

**<kbd>[Symfony2 Service Config Converter](http://converter.rosstuck.com/)</kbd>**

Comment: Works fine except for parent class entries I'm afraid :|