# XML to YAML conversion

Tags: xml, symfony, yaml

I am trying to convert this XML into YAML format in my symfony project. Having some problem with it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <!-- src/Test/WebBundle/Resources/config/services.xml-->
    <container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
        <parameters>
                <parameter key="adoy_oauth2.client.class">OAuth2\Client</parameter>
                <parameter key="test_web.client.class">Test\WebBundle\Service\OAuth2Client</parameter>
            </parameters>

            <services>
                <service id="adoy_oauth2.client" class="%adoy_oauth2.client.class%">
                    <argument>%oauth2_client_id%</argument>
                    <argument>%oauth2_client_secret%</argument>
                </service>

                <service id="test_web.credentials_client" class="%test_web.client.class%">
                    <argument type="service" id="adoy_oauth2.client" />
                    <argument>%oauth2_auth_endpoint%</argument>
                    <argument>%oauth2_token_endpoint%</argument>
                    <argument>%oauth2_redirect_url%</argument>
                    <argument>client_credentials</argument>
                    <argument type="collection">
                        <argument key="client_id">%oauth2_client_id%</argument>
                        <argument key="client_secret">%oauth2_client_secret%</argument>
                    </argument>
                </service>

                <service id="test_web.authorize_client" class="%test_web.client.class%">
                    <argument type="service" id="adoy_oauth2.client" />
                    <argument>%oauth2_auth_endpoint%</argument>
                    <argument>%oauth2_token_endpoint%</argument>
                    <argument>%oauth2_redirect_url%</argument>
                    <argument>authorization_code</argument>
                    <argument type="collection">
                        <argument key="redirect_uri">%oauth2_redirect_url%</argument>
                    </argument>
                </service>
            </services>
</container>
```

This is YAML I tried:

```
parameters:
     adoy_oauth2.client.class: OAuth2\Client
     test_web.client.class: Lyke\WebBundle\Service\OAuth2Client

services:
     adoy_oauth2.client:
         class: %adoy_oauth2.client.class%
         arguments: [%oauth2_client_id%, %oauth2_client_secret%]
     test_web.credentials_client:
         test_: %lyke_web.client.class%
         arguments:
             - @adoy_oauth2.client
             - [%oauth2_auth_endpoint%, %oauth2_token_endpoint%, %oauth2_redirect_url%, "client_credentials"]
             - {
                    collection:
                    {
                        client_id: %oauth2_client_id%,
                        client_secret: %oauth2_client_secret%
                    }
               }
     test_web.authorize_client:
         test_: %lyke_web.client.class%
         arguments: 
             - @adoy_oauth2.client
             - [%oauth2_auth_endpoint%, %oauth2_token_endpoint%, %oauth2_redirect_url%, "authorization_code"]
             - {
                    collection:
                    {
                        redirect_uri: %oauth2_redirect_url%
                    }
               }
```

I am really not sure how to convert it correctly, I think having two arguments isn't something right. Please help..

Comment: There is a tool out now that allows you to have this automatically converted: http://converter.rosstuck.com

Comment: @RelaXNow, I faced same issue about converting configs and found converter you mentioned and later this question and wrapped you comment in answer as the result :).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML to YAML convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137715/xml-to-yaml-convert)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [*@RelaXNow*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4512/relaxnow) in the comment under the question, there is a neat and simple online tool for converting Symfony *[XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)* config to *[YAML](http://yaml.org/)*.

**<kbd>[Symfony2 Service Config Converter](http://converter.rosstuck.com/)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

Your `collection` argument makes the problem; I tried with your XML and get a `YAML`, and it seems valid in online tools, PLease try with this,

```
parameters:
     adoy_oauth2.client.class: OAuth2\Client
     test_web.client.class: Lyke\WebBundle\Service\OAuth2Client

services:
     adoy_oauth2.client:
         class: "%adoy_oauth2.client.class%"
         arguments: ["%oauth2_client_id%", "%oauth2_client_secret%"]
     test_web.credentials_client:
         test_: "%lyke_web.client.class%"
         arguments:
             - "@adoy_oauth2.client"
             - ["%oauth2_auth_endpoint%", "%oauth2_token_endpoint%", "%oauth2_redirect_url%", "client_credentials",[client_id: "%oauth2_client_id%",client_secret: "%oauth2_client_secret%"]]
     test_web.authorize_client:
         test_: "%lyke_web.client.class%"
         arguments: 
             - "@adoy_oauth2.client"
             - ["%oauth2_auth_endpoint%", "%oauth2_token_endpoint%", "%oauth2_redirect_url%", "authorization_code",[redirect_uri: "%oauth2_redirect_url%"]]
```

[YAML Converter](http://codebeautify.org/yaml-to-json-xml-csv#) and [online YAML parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/)  says its a valid `yaml`